# JSF2.0 simple file input

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2

I'm trying to add a very simple file input to my webapp which I'm doing using JSF2.0 and RichFaces 3.3.3, the thing is I really dislike the richfaces fileInput component and I'm looking for something simpler (in terms of use and looks), so far I've found:

- tomahawk's fileInput - but tomahawk only supports JSF1.2
- trinidad fileInput - but trinidad for JSF2.0 is in alpha stage
- primefaces - but of course they won't work with RichFaces 3.3.3 (only 4.0 which are in beta)

Are there any other options? I need something really simple like a normal html file input component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to do two things:

1. Create a Filter which puts the `multipart/form-data` items in a custom map and replace the original request parameter map with it so that the normal `request.getParameter()` process keeps working.
2. Create a JSF 2.0 custom component which renders a `input type="file"` and which is aware of this custom map and can obtain the uploaded files from it.

@taher has already given a link where you could find insights and code snippets. The JSF 2.0 snippets should be reuseable. You yet have to modify the `MultipartMap` to use the good 'ol [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) API instead of the Servlet 3.0 API.

If I have time, I will by end of day rewrite it and post it here.

---

**Update**: I almost forgot you, I did a quick update to replace Servlet 3.0 API by Commons FileUpload API, it should work:

```
package net.balusc.http.multipart;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class MultipartMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {

    // Constants ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "parts";
    private static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.

    // Vars ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private String encoding;
    private String location;

    // Constructors -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Construct multipart map based on the given multipart request and file upload location. When
     * the encoding is not specified in the given request, then it will default to <tt>UTF-8</tt>.
     * @param multipartRequest The multipart request to construct the multipart map for.
     * @param location The location to save uploaded files in.
     * @throws ServletException If something fails at Servlet level.
     * @throws IOException If something fails at I/O level.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // ServletFileUpload#parseRequest() isn't parameterized.
    public MultipartMap(HttpServletRequest multipartRequest, String location)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        multipartRequest.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, this);

        this.encoding = multipartRequest.getCharacterEncoding();
        if (this.encoding == null) {
            multipartRequest.setCharacterEncoding(this.encoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        }
        this.location = location;

        try {
            List<FileItem> parts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(multipartRequest);
            for (FileItem part : parts) {
                if (part.isFormField()) {
                    processFormField(part);
                } else if (!part.getName().isEmpty()) {
                    processFileField(part);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Parsing multipart/form-data request failed.", e);
        }
    }

    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public Object get(Object key) {
        Object value = super.get(key);
        if (value instanceof String[]) {
            String[] values = (String[]) value;
            return values.length == 1 ? values[0] : Arrays.asList(values);
        } else {
            return value; // Can be File or null.
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see ServletRequest#getParameter(String)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If this field is actually a File field.
     */
    public String getParameter(String name) {
        Object value = super.get(name);
        if (value instanceof File) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is a File field. Use #getFile() instead.");
        }
        String[] values = (String[]) value;
        return values != null ? values[0] : null;
    }

    /**
     * @see ServletRequest#getParameterValues(String)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If this field is actually a File field.
     */
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        Object value = super.get(name);
        if (value instanceof File) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is a File field. Use #getFile() instead.");
        }
        return (String[]) value;
    }

    /**
     * @see ServletRequest#getParameterNames()
     */
    public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
        return Collections.enumeration(keySet());
    }

    /**
     * @see ServletRequest#getParameterMap()
     */
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
        Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : entrySet()) {
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value instanceof String[]) {
                map.put(entry.getKey(), (String[]) value);
            } else {
                map.put(entry.getKey(), new String[] { ((File) value).getName() });
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    /**
     * Returns uploaded file associated with given request parameter name.
     * @param name Request parameter name to return the associated uploaded file for.
     * @return Uploaded file associated with given request parameter name.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If this field is actually a Text field.
     */
    public File getFile(String name) {
        Object value = super.get(name);
        if (value instanceof String[]) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is a Text field. Use #getParameter() instead.");
        }
        return (File) value;
    }

    // Helpers ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Process given part as Text part.
     */
    private void processFormField(FileItem part) {
        String name = part.getFieldName();
        String[] values = (String[]) super.get(name);

        if (values == null) {
            // Not in parameter map yet, so add as new value.
            put(name, new String[] { part.getString() });
        } else {
            // Multiple field values, so add new value to existing array.
            int length = values.length;
            String[] newValues = new String[length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(values, 0, newValues, 0, length);
            newValues[length] = part.getString();
            put(name, newValues);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process given part as File part which is to be saved in temp dir with the given filename.
     */
    private void processFileField(FileItem part) throws IOException {

        // Get filename prefix (actual name) and suffix (extension).
        String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(part.getName());
        String prefix = filename;
        String suffix = "";
        if (filename.contains(".")) {
            prefix = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
            suffix = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
        }

        // Write uploaded file.
        File file = File.createTempFile(prefix + "_", suffix, new File(location));
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            input = new BufferedInputStream(part.getInputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
        }

        put(part.getFieldName(), file);
        part.delete(); // Cleanup temporary storage.
    }

}
```

You still need both the `MultipartFilter` and `MultipartRequest` classes as described in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html). You only need to remove the `@WebFilter` annotation and map the filter on an `url-pattern` of `/*` along with an `<init-param>` of `location` wherein you specify the absolute path where the uploaded files are to be stored. You can use the JSF 2.0 custom file upload component as described in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html) unchanged.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, if you say that replacing the MultipartMap with Apache Commons FileUpload will work then I guess I'll try it out!

Comment: Is this possible to do without without creating a custom component? I'd prefer to use the jsf-2 api without specifying a vendor, which seemed required to construct the custom component as described in your blog at [link](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html)

Comment: @Rasmus: Yes, but you need at least a filter which puts the multipart parts back as request parameters. Without creating a custom component, you're all by yourself responsible for gathering and validating the submitted value and updating the model value and invoking any listener.

Comment: Ended up using tomahawk instead, as suggested by you in another question. Seems to work pretty well, the primefaces upload component i used before was very fragile.

Comment: @Rasmus: related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload/5424229#5424229

Answer (score 0):

Dear either you have to use rich:uploadFile or make custom component in JSF by following http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html

Comment: The problem here is that I'm using Tomcat 6, which doesn't support Servlet 3.0 (and it isn't my call to change to tomcat 7).

Answer (score 0):

After I also tried tomahawk, I mentioned that it does not work with AJAX. So I decided to hack rich:fileUpload and perform the click on add button over a a4j:commandButton. Here's the code:

```
<a4j:form id="myForm">
  <a4j:commandButton id="myButton" value="Upload" title="Upload" styleClass="myButtonClass"
                     onclick="document.getElementById('myForm:myFileUpload:file').click()/>

  <rich:fileUpload id="myFileUpload" maxFilesQuantity="1" autoclear="true"
                   immediateUpload="true" styleClass="invisibleClass"
                   fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.uploadListener}"/>
</a4j:form>
```

`myForm:myFileUpload:file` is the input-Element (`type="file"`) for the Add-Button. invisibleClass should only contain `display:none;`. With `style="display:none;"` it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can used rich faces 3.3.3 file upload.
```

Step 1 : fileUpload.xhtml

```
<rich:fileUpload id="fileupload" addControlLabel="Browse"
                                                required="true" 
                                                fileUploadListener="#{testForm.listener}"
                                                acceptedTypes="xml"
                                                ontyperejected="alert('Only xml files are accepted');"
                                                maxFilesQuantity="1" listHeight="57px" listWidth="100%"
                                                disabled="#{testForm..disabled}" >
                                                <a4j:support event="onclear"
                                                    action="#{testForm..clearUploadData}"
                                                    reRender="fileupload" />
                                            </rich:fileUpload>
```

Step 2: FileUpload.java

```
public class FileUpload implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String Name;
    private String mime;
    private long length;
    private byte [] file;
    private String absolutePath;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the file
     */
    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    /**
     * @param file the file to set
     */
    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    /**
     * @param mime the mime to set
     */
    public void setMime(String mime) {
        this.mime = mime;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
        int extDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if(extDot > 0){
            String extension = name.substring(extDot +1);
            if("txt".equals(extension)){
                mime="txt";
            } else if("xml".equals(extension)){
                mime="xml";

            } else {
                mime = "unknown file";
            }
        }
    }
    public long getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public void setLength(long length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getMime(){
        return mime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the absolutePath
     */
    public String getAbsolutePath() {
        return absolutePath;
    }

    /**
     * @param absolutePath the absolutePath to set
     */
    public void setAbsolutePath(String absolutePath) {
        this.absolutePath = absolutePath;
    }
}
```

Step 3 :TestForm // calling listner

```
/**
 * 
 * @param event
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void listener(UploadEvent event) throws Exception{
        UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
        FileUpload file = new FileUpload();
        file.setLength(item.getData().length);
        file.setFile(item.getData());
        file.setName(item.getFileName());
        files.add(file);

 }
```

Comment: Did you read the question? OP clearly stated that he didn't want to use that.