# Tomcat: get file-path

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, path

I have an JSP-application on a tomcat.

I have a application to upload files.

Now i want to delete the files. I know the relative url "aktionen/100" but I don´t know the absolute path.

On Localhost it is "C://daten/client/" for example.
But i want to get them dynamically because if I host it then it is an other path.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on relative paths is a bad idea from the beginning on. Make the upload folder externally configureable by for example a VM argument or a properties file setting. E.g. when you start Tomcat, add this VM argument

```
-Dupload.location=/path/to/uploads
```

Then you can get it as follows:

```
File uploadFolder = new File(System.getProperty("upload.location"));
File uploadedFile = new File(uploadFolder, "aktionen/100");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [How I save and retrieve an image on my server in a java webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516387/how-i-save-and-retrieve-an-image-on-my-server)