# (Explanation required) retrieve image from computer folder

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been following http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/07/fileservlet.html but couldn't get it right with my code as i am not understanding much of it ...

```
filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"photo.jpg";
    System.out.println(filePath);
    // Get requested file by path info.
    String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();
    System.out.println(requestedFile);
    // Check if file is actually supplied to the request URI.
    if (requestedFile == null) {
        // Do your thing if the file is not supplied to the request URI.
        // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning page, or just ignore it.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        System.out.println("terminates");
        return;
    }
```

what i get out of this is the program terminates here as the requestedFile is null all the time... can anyone help me go through the code.... Any Help will be appreciated !!! Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I really don't understand any of it ... is there anyway you could help me understand this !!!

Comment: So you want to read file in servlet?

Comment: yeah ! I would be glad if you could help me !

Comment: what is the path for the image.jpg?? i mean the real path?

Comment: well first i uploaded the image into the images folder that's located exactly here "C:\Users\Roshan Shahukhal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\E-Drivers Licensing System\build\web\images\" ... now i want to retrieve that image and display in the view page !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this code on *hackathon* so it's not clean. You can see example [here](https://github.com/gkiko/CloudLibrary), more specifically [here](https://github.com/gkiko/CloudLibrary/blob/master/src/model/ImageService.java).

BalusC explains it better [stackoverflow.com/a/8521981/660408](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8521981/660408)

I created 'resources' folder in eclipse project directory and placed images there.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        File file = new File("D:\\FreeUni-enterprise\\CloudLibrary\\resources", filename);
        ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your project ! I will go through and see what comes out of it !!! anyway, thanks again !