# CommandButton action not invoked when using Tomahawk t:inputFileUpload

Tags: jsp, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, tomahawk

I'm using JSF 2.1 with JSP files. I tried to use JSF 2.1 with Facelet files, but didn't get Tomahawk (MyFaces extension) to work.

I'm trying to upload a file using Tomahawk. My form looks like follows:

```
<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>FILE UPLOAD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <t:inputFileUpload value="#{fileUploadBean.upFile}"
                                   size="25"
                                   required="true" /><br/>
                <h:commandButton value="Validar" action="#{fileUploadBean.upload}" />
            </h:form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

and my bean is (as I'm using JSF 2.1, I don't need to use `faces-config.xml` and I use annotations):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile;

/**
 *
 * @author federico.martinez
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FileUploadBean {

    private UploadedFile upFile;

    public UploadedFile getUpFile(){
        return upFile;
    }

    public void setUpFile(UploadedFile upFile){
        this.upFile = upFile;
    }

    public String upload(){
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = upFile.getInputStream();
            long size = upFile.getSize();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)size];
            is.read(buffer,0,(int)size);
            is.close();
            System.out.println("File Upload Successful.");
            return "processing-file";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileUploadBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return "error-lf";
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FileUploadBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Well that's it, but finally the problem is when I click on h:commandButton, it doesn't do anything. It seems like the method "upload" from my bean isn't working or something. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Tomahawk documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/extensionsFilter.html), you need to register `ExtensionsFilter` in `web.xml`. It's the one responsible for parsing `multipart/form-data` requests and converting the multipart form data parts to normal request parameters and attributes, so that the `FacesServlet` can continue using them. If you don't register the `ExtensionsFilter`, then the `FacesServlet` can't do anything because there are no request parameters in order to determine the model values to be updated and actions to be invoked.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload/5424229#5424229) - A mini tutorial.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you should really consider using Facelets instead of JSP. It offers so many advantages over JSP, such as [templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959), [composite components](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) and [ajax support](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxPOSTForm).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and post the results. I don't want to mix questions, but I didn't find a way to use tomahawk using Facelets in Netbeans. If anyone can help me with that...

Comment: You're welcome. The "See also" link shows in detail how to do that.

Comment: Oh My God! This post inspired me haha! Finally everything's working with Facelets!