# How to upload file in RichFaces 4?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

I need to make a file upload function in JSF 2 so I was searching about it and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload) it is possible to do with Tomahawk, which I think is not very stable with JSF 2.
I'm using RichFaces, so I look for it and [found](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf;jsessionid=2C7A1E89A4A3EAFBA3F5499A99B39B43) this which I think more simple, but I'm using richfaces 4.

So I wonder if there's a way to do this with richfaces 4 or do this with JSF 2 only.

Any idea, suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at RichFaces 3.3.x demo site. You need to look at [RichFaces 4.x demo site](http://showcase.richfaces.org/). The [`<rich:fileUpload>` demo page](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky) contains a concrete example with source code.

To do it with pure JSF2, you'd need to create a custom component and parse the multipart/form-data requests yourself. There's a blog about this with complete and concrete examples: [Uploading files with JSF 2.0 and Servlet 3.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html).

Using Tomahawk is only more easy. I'm not sure why you think that it's not very stable.

Comment: Hello my friend, sorry I think I made a misunderstanding about Tomahawk. At the end I prefer to use richfaces, which I was using already in my project =) . Thanks.

Comment: Just for curious, what is your name ? It is really BalusC ?Or Balus ? (I'm asking here 'cause don't know other way to contact you).If you don't want to answer that's ok mate, I really enjoy all your teachings, really, thanks.

Comment: My real name is Bauke. See also my [SO user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) and several other places which I linked (in)directly in my SO user profile, such as my blog, Careers profile, Linkedin profile, etc. On the "frontpage" of [my blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com) you can find a little history of the nickname "BalusC".

Comment: Nice to meet you my friend, Bauke. =)