# How to create h:selectOneRadio options with textarea, textbox and fileupload fields?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to make the following form in JSF 2.0 but a have some troubles:

[image: screenshot]

1. How can I make `<h:selectOneRadio>`s with textboxes and textareas inside?
2. How can I disbale the textareas or textboxes when the radio buton isn't selected?

---

**Update**: in fact, I have nothing yet about that form. I have only the basic datatable, I'm trying that:

```
<h:column>
  <h:selectOneRadio id="radio" layout="pageDirection" onclick="uncheckOthers(this)" > 
    <f:selectItem id="radio_1" itemLabel="Accesion Number: ">
      <h:inputTextarea id="radio" />
      <!-- Or another one objet distinct to <f:selectItem> -->
    </f:selectItem>
  </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:column>
```

I found the `uncheckOthers()` function in this web and the another function of which I think it does the same:

```
function seleccionarSequencesType(x){
    document.getElementById("gi").disabled=true;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.solicitud.sequencesType.length; i++) {
        if (document.solicitud.sequencesType[i].checked) {
            inhabilitar(document.getElementById(document.solicitud.sequencesType[i].value), false);
            //document.getElementById(x.value).disabled=false;
        } else {
            inhabilitar(document.getElementById(document.solicitud.sequencesType[i].value), true);
            //document.getElementById(document.solicitud.sequencesType[i].value).disabled=true;
        }
    }
}

function uncheckOthers(radio) {
    var name = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
    var elements = radio.form.elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].name.substring(elements[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == name) {
            elements[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
    radio.checked = true;
}
```

I have a basic bean with `String` properties to save the information of the textareas, but it isn't fully developed yet, because at first I want to achieve the above requirement.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard JSF [`<h:selectOneRadio>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html) component doesn't support this. Your best bet using [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) [`<t:selectOneRadio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html) with the `layout` attribute set to `spread`. This enables you to position the individual radio buttons as [`<t:radio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_radio.html) everywhere you want.

To disable the text fields depending on the radio button option value, just let its `disabled` attribute evaluate `true` when the desired radio button option value is not selected.

Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
<style>li { list-style-type: none; }</style>
...
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <t:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{bean.option}" layout="spread">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="text" itemLabel="Text in FASTA format" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="number" itemLabel="Asseccion number" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="file" itemLabel="Upload files" />
        <f:ajax render="@form" />
    </t:selectOneRadio>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <t:panelGrid columns="2">
                <t:panelGroup colspan="2">
                    <t:radio for="options" index="0" />
                </t:panelGroup>
                <h:outputLabel for="text1" value="1st sequence" />                
                <h:inputTextarea id="text1" value="#{bean.text1}" disabled="#{bean.option != 'text'}" />
                <h:outputLabel for="text2" value="2nd sequence" />                
                <h:inputTextarea id="text2" value="#{bean.text2}" disabled="#{bean.option != 'text'}" />
            </t:panelGrid>
        </li>
        <li>
            <t:panelGrid columns="2">
                <t:panelGroup colspan="2">
                    <t:radio for="options" index="1" />
                </t:panelGroup>
                <h:outputLabel for="number1" value="1st id" />                
                <h:inputText id="number1" value="#{bean.number1}" disabled="#{bean.option != 'number'}" />
                <h:outputLabel for="number2" value="2nd id" />                
                <h:inputText id="number2" value="#{bean.number2}" disabled="#{bean.option != 'number'}" />
            </t:panelGrid>
        </li>
        <li>
            <t:panelGrid columns="2">
                <t:panelGroup colspan="2">
                    <t:radio for="options" index="2" />
                </t:panelGroup>
                <h:outputLabel for="file1" value="1st sequence" />                
                <t:inputFileUpload id="file1" value="#{bean.file1}" disabled="#{bean.option != 'file'}" />
                <h:outputLabel for="file2" value="2nd sequence" />                
                <t:inputFileUpload id="file2" value="#{bean.file2}" disabled="#{bean.option != 'file'}" />
            </t:panelGrid>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Please note that Tomahawk also offers a [`<t:panelGroup>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_panelGroup.html) which adds the `colspan` support on top of the standard [`<h:panelGroup>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/panelGroup.html) and also a [`<t:inputFileUpload>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_inputFileUpload.html) to browse and select files. The latter requires the form's encoding type to be set to `multipart/form-data`. This in turn requires the `ExtensionsFilter` to be registered in `web.xml` as shown in this mini-tutorial: [JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload/5424229#5424229).

Answer (score 0):

1. A radio button is a radio button, period. The textboxes should be separate elements (the nicest solution is to create custom components that include the radio button and the textboxes/file upload fields)
2. Use javascript. It gets ugly combined with JSF, but if you keep it in external files you should be fine.

Comment: 1) Perhaps you didn't understand the limitations of `<h:selectOneRadio>`. 2) Not necessary.