# Tomahawk MyFaces File Upload Component not showing on screen

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I am trying to use tomahawk MyFaces file upload component t:inputFileUpload. I followed the example at [JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload), with one change-instead of copying files to /lib, I used maven. There are no errors or warnings, but the file upload component is not showing up. Only the submit button shows on the screen. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Check the rendered HTML page. Perhaps it still contains `<t:inputFileUpload>`. In this case you may have forgotten to add the namespace for the prefix `t` to your file like this:

```
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
```

If the prefix isn't defined, the tags are simply not processed and directly rendered to the output.

Comment: I have defined the prefix. However, the rendered HTML page still contains <t:inputFileUpload>

Comment: Are you sure you added the Tomahawk JAR to your project?