# How to get the uploaded file to read and get data in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

In my UI, user will click on browse and select one excel file and on click of import it comes to Action Class where I have hardcoded the file location like this

```
workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:/Docs/MNC/document.xls")); 
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet");
```

I just want once the user browse and select the excel on click of import it should come to action class for reading and retrieving data from excel, how can I get the file for reading on click of import?

Comment: How exactly are you in your UI asking for the file selection? Using Tomahawk `<t:inputFileUpload>`? Or RichFaces `<rich:fileUpload>`? Or PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>`? Etc. By the way, do you **understand** the answer posted to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314003/how-to-get-the-uploaded-file-path-in-jsf ? If not, then it's not worth the effort to keep asking basically the same question over and over.

Comment: Yes i have understood but lil confused as i am very ne to JSF. In my UI i have one table, and one browse and import buton. I need to import one excel sheet and and by reading some data in that excel file i have t populate r display in my UI table.