# JSF not saving session

Tags: jsf, session, youtube-api, sessionid

I am writing a JSF web app that uses youtube's data api to view/upload youtube videos through the site. Part of using this api is when the user uploads a video, a post is sent to youtube with a redirect parameter so the user is sent back to my site when the upload is complete. My session beans work fine while the user is within the site, but all their values are lost once they post to youtube and are redirected back. This is an issue because with the session lost they are effectively logged out and can't be redirected back to the admin page. I noticed in the server monitor that after the post the session id changes, so I assume this is the problem, but I have no idea how to ensure their session persists through the post and redirect. Does anyone have any suggestions? I have tried changing the state saving method to both client and server. I am new to JSF and not sure what else to try.

The session beans are using @ManagedBean and @SessionScoped

Here is the code for the upload form if this helps, the uploadUrl being the youtube url + redirect parameter.

```
<form action="#{adminbean.uploadUrl}" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="file"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="token" value="#{adminbean.token.token}"/>
     <h:commandButton id ="addMatch" type="submit" value="Upload Match" />
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF 2.0 File upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

I think i had same issue earlier, but only on GoogleApp Engine service (on production server, not on development enviroment).

The problem might be that server don't save current bean state before redirecting. That can cause very nasty redirection loop.

Try to create and register phase listener according to this post:
**https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297154/2068284**

This worked for me.