# Ajax listener not working with inputFile

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload

First of all, I'm using JSF 2.2.7 and GlassFish 4 in NetBeans 8.0.
Second, sorry if I left any useful info out. This is my first question in here, so I may forget something. Also, english isn't my first language. Sorry for typos/grammar.

So, here's my problem: I'm uploading files with h:inputFile and I need an ajax listener for it.
After noticing that it wasn't working as I expected, I decided to do some testing with a listener that prints "Test", but it's never fired with h:inputFile. I've tried with h:commandButton and h:commandLink and they both work fine.
For further testing, I created a new project using the same test code and everything works, including the listener in h:inputFile.

What I want to know is why it doesn't work in my main project and why it works in the test project. What am I missing here? And how can I make it work in my main project?

Here are some (but not all, since I lost track) things that I've tried/checked so far, after looking for answers:

- There are no nested forms. The said xhtml is in a ui:composition, but even taking that into account, there are no nested forms.
- Its form has *enctype="multipart/form-data"*
- I've tried changing the method to *uploadTest(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)* and the listener to *listener="#{submitFormBean.uploadTest}"* [without the ()]
- I've played with the various *event="..."* and *execute="..."* (didn't think it would solve my problem, but, well, I had to try)

The code follows below:

xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="btnTest">
        <f:ajax listener="#{submitFormBean.uploadTest()}"/>` --> works in both projects`
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink id="lnkTest" value="Test">
        <f:ajax listener="#{submitFormBean.uploadTest()}"/>` --> works in both projects`
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="fileTest">            
        <f:ajax listener="#{submitFormBean.uploadTest()}"/>` --> works only in test project`
    </h:inputFile>
</h:form>
```

bean

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "submitFormBean")
public class SubmitFormBean{

    public SubmitFormBean() {
    }

    public void uploadTest(){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to do what I needed in jQuery, but first I decided to try the following and it solved my problem:

right click project/properties/libraries
in the *compile* tab, I removed and readded the JSF 2.2.7 .jar

It was already there, but for some reason wasn't working. I still don't know what went wrong, but it's working now.

Answer (score -1):

With multipart/form-data in JSF form, you have to do additional configuration to make it works.

You can refer to other questions:
[commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-backing-bean-action-method-not-invoked/2120183#2120183)

[JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload/5424229#5424229)

And

[How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083)

Comment: OP is using JSF 2.2 `<h:inputFile>` which uses Servlet 3.0 native file upload support.

Comment: Exactly. The first link was when I first read about looking for nested forms, by the way.
However, I'm under the impression that my problem could be related to some config/library which I don't know about and may be missing in the main project. Perhaps it makes no sense, though, but it's just a guess.
Anyway, thanks for your time!