# Ajax listener not working with JSF2.2 inputFile

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, glassfish-4, jelastic

Hi my problem is somewhat similar to the following:
[ajax-listener-not-working-with-inputfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044320/ajax-listener-not-working-with-inputfile)

I am able to upload files using an AJAX call in my local environment and everything works as expected. However, when I deploy the war file onto Jelastic PaaS, the AJAX listener does not seem to be working.

I've tried updating to JSF2.2 on Jelastic by replacing the jar under 
glassfish\modules and restarting the server, as suggested here: 
[JSF-working-properly-AJAX-file](http://www.coderanch.com/t/629542/JSF/java/JSF-working-properly-AJAX-file)

But this does not seem to have fixed the problem.

I've even created a very simple test similar to the one used in the first link and I am still having no luck.

xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>JSF Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="btnTest" value="Command Button">
        <f:ajax listener="#{submitFormBean.uploadTest()}"/> --> This works.
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink id="lnkTest" value="Command Link">
        <f:ajax listener="#{submitFormBean.uploadTest()}"/> --> This works.
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="fileTest">            
        <f:ajax listener="#{submitFormBean.uploadTest()}"/> --> This input file using Ajax call doesn't work
    </h:inputFile>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "submitFormBean")
public class SubmitFormBean{

    public SubmitFormBean() {
    }

    public void uploadTest(){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Been stuck on this for a couple of days now so any help would be greatly appreciated. As mentioned, this works fine on my local development environment, but fails when deployed onto Jelastic's Glassfish4.

Comment: Which Mojarra version exactly did you try? Which GlassFish version exactly are you using? GF 4.0 is the very first release and therefore bug ridden. Grab current latest available and retry.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for the reply. I've tried Mojarra 2.2.10 and 2.3, both with no luck. The GlashFish version on Jelastic is 4.1(Build 13). On My own development environment, which works fine, I am using GlassFish 4.0 (Build 89).

Comment: @kbgnat, could you please provide an additional information, such as logs, server responses, etc.? Also, it will be great to look at your live app.

Comment: @Aless, unfortunately there are no logs or server responses I can post as the listener isn't picking up the ajax call. The app is still being developed, so is only running on Jelastic when being tested. Sorry I am unable to provide any more additional information.

Comment: What I have noticed though, is that using the simple commandButton, commandLink and inputFile test page I created, the listener also fails to pick up the commandButton and commandLink calls if my last action was to click on the fileInput.

Comment: @kbgnat, do you use non-standard ports (instead of 80, 8080, 433, etc.) for the listener?

Comment: @Aless, it's been configured to use the default ports. Port 8080 for HTTP, port 8181 for HTTPS and port 4848 for Adminsitration.

Comment: The following error was caught using firebug after selecting a file to upload: TypeError: partialResponse is undefined