# How to get JSF to upload file with Apache Commons FileUpload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, apache-commons-fileupload

I know how to do file upload using Primefaces or using Tomahawk, however, I am trying to doing file upload using Apache Commons FileUpload and so far I am having a bit of road block. Even though my form use `multipart/form-data`, when I submit my form, the content type become `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Here is my code

```
<h:body>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Upload File
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{viewBean.submit}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Here is my `ViewBean`

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {
    public void submit() {
        String url = "/FileUploadServlet";
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try {
            String contentType = context.getExternalContext().getRequestContentType();
            context.getExternalContext().dispatch(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception when calling Servlet", e);
        } finally {
            context.responseComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

So when I try to print the content type above, it showed `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If I put `ajax="false"` to my `p:commandButton`, then the `submit()` method is not even invoked, but if I take out `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (still keep `ajax="false"`), then `submit()` is invoked but it is not multipart, it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so apache commons fileupload throw an exception since it is not multipart. Seems like whatever I do, I cant seems to get the multipart requrest. Please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *So when I try to print the content type above, it showed application/x-www-form-urlencoded.*

The `<p:commandButton>` sends by default an ajax request of level 1 `XMLHttpRequest`. This does **not** support `multipart/form-data`. Only [level 2 `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) supports it, but it's only supported in the newest browsers (those also supporting HTML5) and not implemented in JSF JS API nor in PrimeFaces JS API.

---

> *If I put ajax="false" to my p:commandButton, then the submit() method is not even invoked*

This way however a fullworthy `multipart/form-data` **will** be sent. That the submit method is not invoked is just because JSF prior to version 2.2 does not support `multipart/form-data` requests out the box. JSF collects the submitted data by default using `request.getParameter()` and `getParameterMap()` on the underlying HTTP servlet request. However, this will return `null` when an encoding other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is been used. As JSF determines the to-be-invoked action method based on submitted data, it won't be able to locate and invoke it when the data is `null`.

In theory, if you create a `Filter` which uses Apache Commons FileUpload or the new Servlet 3.0 [`request.getPart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart%28java.lang.String%29)/[`getParts()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) methods to extract the data from the `multipart/form-data` request and wraps the current HTTP servlet request with a custom implementation which overrides the `getParameter()` calls wherein a mapping of the extracted data is been supplied, then JSF will be able to do the needed job based on results of `getParameter()` calls. You can find a concrete example utilizing the Servlet 3.0 API in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html) and the same example which is slightly changed to utilize Apache Commons FileUpload in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459743/jsf2-0-simple-file-input/3467582#3467582).

The upcoming JSF 2.2 will have a new `<h:inputFile>` component which is bindable to a Servlet 3.0 [`Part`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) property.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{bean.file}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
private Part file;
```

JSF 2.2 final release is scheduled for late end of Q1, but is currently available as a snapshot release.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very nice to know all this information.

Comment: @BalusC I did as you have said to create a `Filter`, but the action method is not firing if the `h:form` has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. I am in JSF 1.2. Can you please tell me why this happening? I have asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242293/hcommandbutton-is-not-firing-action-if-the-hform-has-enctype-multipart-form-d)

Comment: @Tapas: I've posted an answer. Please don't forget the `[jsf]` tag on the future questions. I haven't seen your question because I don't browse `[jsf-1.2]` on a regular basis.